# Redirect whole shop prefix to another without plugin

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have shop structure like:

```
https://example.com/shop/product-name
```

About 900 products in total.

Now I want to change the `/shop/` to `product` and all link for products to become

```
https://example.com/product/product-name
https://example.com/product/product-name-2
https://example.com/product/product-name-3
...
```

I've tried with

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/(.*)$ /product/$1
```

also with

```
RewriteRule ^/?shop/(.*)$ product/$1 [R=301,L]
```

also

```
redirect 301 /shop/ /product/
```

Nothing work. When I click on link with `/shop/...` it doesn't redirect me.

This is my whole `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/(.*)$ /product/$1
RewriteRule ^/?shop/(.*)$ product/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: have you created product page and assign that page to woocommerce as a shop/loop page ? and after that use your permalink for woocommerce and htaccess redirection

Comment: Yes, they were all `/shop/product-name` and now I added new products and changed the permalinks for shop to `/products`. But some old product wont redirect me. I have their analogs with `products/...`

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager-for-woocommerce/ try with this plugin

Comment: I want to use htaccess for this not plugin